# How to set OnClickListener to a diffrent class other then Activiy class

Tags: java, android, controller, onclicklistener

I want to run my OnClickListener in a Controller class instead of the MainActivity class. Below is my code that I wrote to test it, but Android emulator just crash moments befor it opend!

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btn;
TextView txt;

Controller controll;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    controll = new Controller();
}

public Button getBtn(){
    return btn;
}

public TextView getTextView(){
    return txt;
}
```

Controller class:

```
public class Controller {
MainActivity main;
Button btn;
TextView txt;

public Controller(){
    this.main = new MainActivity();

    btn = main.getBtn();
    txt = main.getTextView();
}

public void listners(){
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txt.setText("Yes, it worked!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is listners() method called in your code?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Controller` class, you are creating a new instance of `MainActivity`, which will not have `btn` and `txt` initialized. Instead make your `Controller` class receive an argument of `MainActivity`:

```
public Controller(MainActivity activity){
    this.main = activity;

    btn = main.getBtn();
    txt = main.getTextView();
}
```

And then send the reference of the `MainActivity` to the `Controller` class when instantiating:

```
controll = new Controller(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. You mustn't instantiate an Activity like this. If you do this all its callbacks are not called and it's pretty useless then.

In your case you can just pass as instance of an activity to your `Controller` and here do what you need.

```
controll = new Controller(this);
```

In your controller:

```
public Controller (MainActivity activity);
this.activity = activity;
```

And then call your methods `getBtn` and `getTextView` like `activity.getBtn()`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that an `Activity` is a *Controller* in *MVC* sense. What you want to have (a class that survives any UI events) is *Model* (and classes like `MyCystomButton` belong to *View*). The bad news about this *Controller* (=Activity) is that it is re-created when the screen turns and in some other less evident cases.

Your code

```
this.main = new MainActivity();
```

creates a new activity *not associated* with the UI elements on the screen, and its function `onCreate()` is not called. No surprize its fields are null.

I recommend to make the pointer to your ControllerThatDoesNotDie (which is in fact a part of *Model*) a static reference (but note that Android may terminate the process and the reference may become null; if this happens, the Bundle argument to onCreate will be not null, and the ControllerThatDoesNotDie.theInstance() will be null).

Now, let the Activity forward the button events to the ControllerThatDoesNotDie:

```
void onMyButton(View v) {
    ControllerThatDoesNotDie.theInstance().onMyButton(v);
    // assuming that theInstance() never returns null, creating the instance if necessary
}
```